# Hardware Virtualization not available in Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization, dell-inspiron, kaspersky

I am installing anti-virus software with a DELL Inspiron 13 5379 laptop with i7 CPU running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition. And, under the setting of "Use hardware virtualization if available", there is a warning saying, "Hardware virtualization is not available. Incompatible hardware or software detected".

However, I double-checked the BIOS setting in the section of "Virtualization Support", and both "Virtualization" and "VT for Direct I/O" are enabled.

I wonder if I missed anything so that the anti-virus complains about virtualization being unavailable?

I highly appreciate your suggestions and hints.

Comment: lots of things can use hardware virtualization now, for example Hyper-V and WSL2 both use it.  Other features like device guard and credential guard use it also.

Comment: If you have any other software that use hardware virtualization, you will be unable to allow your security software to use it, until you uninstall or disable that hardware virtualization.  You will have to provide more specific information by editing your question.